# Spark RFormula Interpretation

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, apache-spark-mllib

I was reading "Spark The Definitive Guide", i came across a code section in MLlib chapter which has the following code:

```
var df = spark.read.json("/data/simple-ml") 
df.orderBy("value2").show()
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula
// Unable to understand the interpretation of this formulae
val supervised = new RFormula().setFormula("lab ~ . + color:value1 + color:value2")
val fittedRF = supervised.fit(df)
val preparedDF = fittedRF.transform(df) 
preparedDF.show()
```

Where /data/simple-ml contains a JSON file containing(e.g):-

"lab":"good","color":"green","value1":1,"value2":14.386294994851129
"lab":"bad","color":"blue","value1":8,"value2":14.386294994851129
"lab":"bad","color":"blue","value1":12,"value2":14.386294994851129
"lab":"good","color":"green","value1":15,"value2":38.9718713375581

you can find the complete data set at https://github.com/databricks/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/blob/master/data/simple-ml/part-r-00000-f5c243b9-a015-4a3b-a4a8-eca00f80f04c.json
and above lines produces the output as:-

[green,good,1,14.386294994851129,**(10,[0,2,3,4,7],[1.0,1.0,14.386294994851129,1.0,14.386294994851129])**,0.0]
[blue,bad,8,14.386294994851129,**(10,[2,3,6,9],[8.0,14.386294994851129,8.0,14.386294994851129])**,1.0]
[blue,bad,12,14.386294994851129,**(10,[2,3,6,9],[12.0,14.386294994851129,12.0,14.386294994851129])**,1.0]
[green,good,15,38.97187133755819,**(10,[0,2,3,4,7],[1.0,15.0,38.97187133755819,15.0,38.97187133755819])**,0.0]

Now i am not able to understand how it is calculating the 5th(marked in bold) column value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 5-th column is a structure representing sparse vectors in Spark. It has three components:

- vector length - in this case all vectors are of length 10 elements
- index array holding the indices of non-zero elements
- value array of non-zero values

So

```
(10,[0,2,3,4,7],[1.0,1.0,14.386294994851129,1.0,14.386294994851129])
```

represent the following sparse vector of length 10 (take the *i*-th value and place it in position *i*):

```
 0       2    3                   4          7
[1.0, 0, 1.0, 14.386294994851129, 1.0, 0, 0, 14.386294994851129, 0, 0]
```

(the positions of the non-zero elements are shown)

What are the individual components of that vector? According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RFormula):

> RFormula produces a vector column of features and a double or string column of label. Like when formulas are used in R for linear regression, string input columns will be one-hot encoded, and numeric columns will be cast to doubles. If the label column is of type string, it will be first transformed to double with `StringIndexer`. If the label column does not exist in the DataFrame, the output label column will be created from the specified response variable in the formula.

`lab ~ . + color:value1 + color:value2` is a special syntax that comes from the R language. It describes a model that regresses the value of `lab` on all the other features plus two interaction (product) terms. You can see the list of all features by printing `fittedRF` and looking at the `ResolvedRFormula` instance it contains:

```
scala> println(fittedRF)
RFormulaModel(
 ResolvedRFormula(
  label=lab,
  terms=[color,value1,value2,{color,value1},{color,value2}],
  hasIntercept=true
 )
) (uid=rFormula_0847e597e817)
```

I've split the output in lines and indented it for readability. So `. + color:value1 + color:value2` expands to `[color,value1,value2,{color,value1},{color,value2}]`. Of those, `color` is a categorical feature and it gets one-hot encoded in a set of indicator features using the following mapping:

- *green* becomes `[1, 0]`
- *blue* becomes `[0, 0]`
- *red* becomes `[0, 1]`

Although you have three categories, only two are used for the encoding. *Blue* in this case gets dropped since its presence has no information value - if it was there, all three columns will always sum to 1, which makes them linearly dependent. The effect of dropping the *blue* category is that it becomes the baseline as part of the intercept and the fitted model predicts what effect changing the category from *blue* to *green* or from *blue* to *red* will have on the label. That particular choice of encoding is a bit arbitrary - on my system the columns for *red* and *green* came out swapped.

`value1` and `value2` are doubles, so they go unchanged in the feature vector. `{color,value1}` is the product of the `color` feature and the `value1` feature, so that is the product of the one-hot encoding of `color` with the scalar `value1`, resulting in three new features. Notice that in this case we cannot drop one category because the interaction makes the "base" value dependent on the value of the second feature in the interaction. Same for `{color,value2}`. So you end up with 2 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 3 or 10 features in total. What you see in the output of `show()` is the assembled vector feature column that can be used as input by other Spark ML classes.

Here is how to read the first row:

```
(10,[0,2,3,4,7],[1.0,1.0,14.386294994851129,1.0,14.386294994851129])
```

is the sparse vector representation of

```
[1.0, 0, 1.0, 14.386294994851129, 1.0, 0, 0, 14.386294994851129, 0, 0]
 |--1--| |2|  |-------3--------|  |---4---|  |----------5-----------|
```

which contains the following individual components:

1. `[1.0, 0, ...]` - `color`, one-hot encoding (minus the linearly dependent third category) of category *green*
2. `[..., 1.0, ...]` - `value1`, value `1`
3. `[..., 14.386294994851129, ...]` - `value2`, value 14,38629...
4. `[..., 1.0, 0, 0, ...]` - `color x value1` interaction term, product of one-hot encoding of *green* (`[1, 0, 0]`) and 1
5. `[..., 14.386294994851129, 0, 0]` - `color x value2` interaction term, product of one-hot encoding of *green* (`[1, 0, 0]`) and 14,38629...

Comment: Brilliant explanation, I am able to understand each and every word except why we are saying blue is dropped and how it becomes the baseline, can you please help me understanding this also.

Comment: Imagine a linear model based on one categorical variable with two categories: `y = a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * x2`, where `x1` and `x2` are the indicators for each category, the `a`s are the fitted model parameters. The only possible values of `x1` and `x2` are either `x1 = 1` and `x2 = 0` (category 1) or `x1 = 0` and `x2 = 1` (category 2), so their sum is always 1. Then we can express `x2` in terms of `x1` as `x2 = 1 - x1` and hence the model becomes `y = a0 + a1 * x1 + a2 * (1 - x1) = (a0 + a2) + (a1 - a2) * x1`. Now look at the value of `y` given the category of the predictor:

Comment: In the original model, when `x1 = 1` and `x2 = 0` (cat. 1), `y = a0 + a1`. If `x1 = 0` and `x2 = 1` (cat. 2), then `y = a0 + a2`. In the case where we expressed `x2` as `1 - x1`, we have: when `x1 = 1` (cat. 1), `y = (a0 + a2) + (a1 - a2) = a0 + a1`, when `x1 = 0` (cat. 2), `y = (a0 + a2)`. So we get the same output, but now the coefficient before `x1` is `a1 - a2`, which is exactly the difference between the weights of the two categories in the starting model. The coefficient of `x2` gets absorbed in the intercept (or base value). Now just repeat the same with three categories.

Comment: Training the model with `x1` and `x2` teaches it to recognise some baseline and the weight of each category separately. Training the model with only `x1` teaches it to recognise the difference between the two weights and absorbs the weight of the second category in the intercept (the baseline). Note that the latter case is more "natural" as the baseline in the former one is artificial - you cannot have both `x1` and `x2` equal to 0, so the model's output is never `a0`.