# what is features and how to interpret in RFormula

Tags: r, pyspark, mlflow

I am trying to understand what an RFormula is in MLflow or spark.

I have found these:

https://george-jen.gitbook.io/data-science-and-apache-spark/rformula
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.RFormula.html

but still cannot understand how to interpret an RFormula fully. I am not sure how to interpret the below table
[image]

based on the formula "y ~ x+ s", y is related to x and s, but in the table when y=0 and x=0 and s =a (i.e. third row), then the features is [0,1] and label is 0, so how shall I interpret this.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290042/spark-rformula-interpretation) but still cannot understand my way through this problem.

Comment: This question was already answered, show below:
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61290042/spark-rformula-interpretation)

Comment: Yes, but as I said in the question and also referred to that link in the question, I cannot follow the logic.  I cannot understand how I shall put the y,x,s,and features together to get the label value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your label is y. You parse x and s in rformula.

x stays the same:

```
+-----------+---+
|      x    | x |
+-----------+---+
|     1.0   |1.0|
|     2.0   |2.0|
|     0.0   |0.0|
+-----------+---+
```

s:

```
+-----------+---+
|       s   | s |
+-----------+---+
|       a   |1.0|
|       b   |0.0|
|       a   |1.0|
+-----------+---+
```

I hope I could answer you question.
Rformula just converts the strings, standarize them and parse them into a vector.

Comment: why does x stay the same, can you explain more? how should I interpret '/' in your answer? why does s change to sth?

Comment: x stays the same, because you have different values, no standarization is needed. If you look at s, then you see a for two times. So the transformer need to give him the same numeric value to standarize them.

Comment: Thanks @JAdel, but I cannot follow how to interpret the features. do you know a source with a good explanation, I could not find much on this topic

Comment: https://databricks.com/de/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly grab this free book. There is a topic with explanation what you are looking for. As I understood, the label was there before. All what Rformula does is to transform your dataframe and add a new column named features which includes the vectorized variables.

Comment: Thanks for the book, I will read chapter 10 and hopefully I can understand this better, will keep you posted, thx

Comment: Thanks for reformatting the table, it is now make sense,